# Is this true:$ E[A|C]=E[A|B∩C]P(!B|C)+E[A|!B∩C]P(!B|C)$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

That is the conditional extension of

$$E[A]=E[A|B]P(B)+E[A|!B]P(!B)$$

$$E[A|C]=E[A|B∩C]P(B|C)+E[A|!B∩C]P(!B|C)$$ allowed me to get the right answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a result of [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation): $$E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$$
This holds in [general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#/Proof_in_the_general_case) as well: $$E[X|Y] = E[E[X|Y,Z]|Y]$$

which is a general case of your expression.